# In WordPress, I want to run a loop to get posts in tabular format

Tags: php, table

I am having difficulty while fetching all the posts in WordPress using while loop. I need to fetch posts in a tabular format in which 1 row should contain 3 column cells.
[image: This is what I am getting right now]

[image: This is how I want it to be seen]

Comment: have you tried any code for that??

Comment: I've a plugin for responsive grid, I tried using it with the shortcodes but it's not working. It is showing a single posts thrice instead showing it in different td cells

Comment: You need to Code through PHP or you want it from the Plugin

Comment: I don't feel to use any plugin. Instead I want to learn to code in PHP. I found one code of PHP but I'm not able to use it.

Comment: Fine i will provide with the code to display in the 3 Column Layout if you use Bootstrap

Comment: Yeah, I need responsive layout. The same layout you can see in 2nd screenshot. Thanks

Comment: Modified my Output as per the Requirements Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is to display the Posts provided you have to pass the `$args` so that it will  fetch all data for you in the loop.

It is mandatory to use bootstrap so that it will be easy for you to use the code for alignment.

```
<?php query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="attachment_image">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="post_title">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Example by Providing the `$args` over to the Code.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'posts',
'orderby'    => 'ID',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order'    => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$results = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $results-> have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $results->have_posts() ) : $results->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="attachment_image">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="post_title">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
</div>
</div>  
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: What $args will contain?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please Check It

Comment: I was confused after seeing your code but the lines-

<?php while ( $results->have_posts() ) : $results->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="attachment_image">

Made my day. I arrange the div code according to your code and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Ha ha but you got the Output Right :)

Comment: I designed for you according to the Output that you have to get that is the reason for getting this mush lines

Comment: With Pleasure: Keep rocking